# why i am getting fatal error for repo init?

Tags: ubuntu, git, repository

Earlier repo init has worked properly, but lately it is throwing below errors,

```
fatal: error unknown url type: https
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

I have tried installing, apt-get install phablet-tools as per one of the stalkexchnage post,since i am using Ubuntu 14.04. However installation failed, Any idea how it can be resolved?

I am using http as proxy for both http and https. Earlier i had both http and https proxy in env variable, even that didn't work.

Comment: It would help to know which command caused the error, what error message you get when trying to install phablet-tools, and which Stackexchange post you mean. Did the repo init error occur before or after installing phablet-tools? Also, I have doubts that you will get much help for an OS version that has been obsolete for a long while.  Is there no way to switch to 18 or 20?

Comment: `git init` doesn't take a URL at all, so it's really not clear what you're referring to here. As berndbausch says, we'll need to know *exactly* the command line you're using that gives you that error.